# Previous 'session time out' error message is not being clean

Tags: django, django-1.5, django-sessions, django-login

I'm using Django 1.5.5, and I'm using the built-in authentication system provided by Django.

I define `SESSION_TIMEOUT=600` in my settings.py, so after 10 minutes idle, user will be redirected to the login page with '**Session timed out**' warning as `request.COOKIES.logout_reason` is displayed on the page. 
The problem is, after user re-login again, and manually log out the system. The 'Session timed out' warning message is still displayed, I suppose that `request.COOKIES.logout_reason` variable should be cleaned up after successfully log in.

What could be the problem and where are the code I might need to look at? I'm inexperienced on Django and haven't found related discussion yet. Thanks.

**Updated:** the login and logout function I use in `django.contrib.auth.views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login as auth_login, logout as auth_logout, get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, PasswordResetForm, SetPasswordForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site

@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    request.session.set_test_cookie()

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)


def logout(request, next_page=None,
           template_name='registration/logged_out.html',
           redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
           current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Logs out the user and displays 'You are logged out' message.
    """
    auth_logout(request)

    if redirect_field_name in request.REQUEST:
        next_page = request.REQUEST[redirect_field_name]
        # Security check -- don't allow redirection to a different host.
        if not is_safe_url(url=next_page, host=request.get_host()):
            next_page = request.path

    if next_page:
        # Redirect to this page until the session has been cleared.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_page)

    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    context = {
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
        'title': _('Logged out')
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
        current_app=current_app)
```

and the `auth_login()` and `auth_logout()` will call to the following functions in `django.contrib.auth.__init__.py`:

```
def login(request, user):
    """
    Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
    have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
    the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
    """
    if user is None:
        user = request.user
    # TODO: It would be nice to support different login methods, like signed cookies.
    if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
        if request.session[SESSION_KEY] != user.pk:
            # To avoid reusing another user's session, create a new, empty
            # session if the existing session corresponds to a different
            # authenticated user.
            request.session.flush()
    else:
        request.session.cycle_key()
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
    request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        request.user = user
    rotate_token(request)
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)


def logout(request):
    """
    Removes the authenticated user's ID from the request and flushes their
    session data.
    """
    # Dispatch the signal before the user is logged out so the receivers have a
    # chance to find out *who* logged out.
    user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
    if hasattr(user, 'is_authenticated') and not user.is_authenticated():
        user = None
    user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

    request.session.flush()
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

Comment: What is the logout/login view you are using?

Comment: hi @BurhanKhalid My login/logout functions mainly use `login()` and `logout()` functions in `django.contrib.auth.views.py`. Is there any other information I can provide to you?

Comment: Update the question with the actual views you are using for logging in and logging out.

Comment: What is `auth_login` and `auth_logout`?

Comment: @dan-klasson I included them, but again it is still built-in code in django.contrib.auth

Comment: So you are doing `import login as auth_login`?

Comment: @dan-klasson Yes, I just added the include  statement `from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login as auth_login, logout as auth_logout` to the code section